# Timing issues with playback of the HTML5 Audio API

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I'm using the following code to try to play a sound clip with the HTML5 Audio API:

```
HTMLAudioElement.prototype.playClip  = function(startTime, stopTime) { 
  this.stopTime = stopTime;
  this.currentTime = startTime;
  this.play();
  $(this).bind('timeupdate', function(){
    if (this.ended || this.currentTime >= stopTime) {
      this.pause();
      $(this).unbind('timeupdate');
    }
  });

}
```

I utilize this new `playClip` method as follows. First I have a link with some `data` attributes:

```
<a href=# data-stop=1.051 data-start=0.000>And then I was thinking,</a>
```

And finally this bit of jQuery which runs on `$(document).ready` to hook up a click on the link with the playback:  $('a').click(function(ev){

```
  $('a').click(function(ev){

    var start = $(this).data('start'),
        stop = $(this).data('stop'),
        audio = $('audio').get(0),
        $audio = $(audio);

    ev.preventDefault();

    audio.playClip(start,stop);


  })
```

This approach seems to work, but there's a frustrating bug: sometimes, the playback of a given clip plays beyond the correct `data-stop` time.

I suspect it could have something to do with the timing of the `timeupdate` event, but I'm no JS guru and I don't know how to begin debugging the problem. Here are a few clues I've gathered:

- The same behavior appears to come up in both FF and Chrome.
- The playback of a given clip actually seems to vary a bit -- if I play the same clip a couple times in a row, it may over-play a different amount of time on each playing.

Is the problem here the inherent accuracy of the Audio API? My app needs milliseconds.

Is there a problem with the way I'm using jQuery to bind and unbind the `timeupdate` event? I tried using the jQuery-less approach with `addEventListener` but I couldn't get it to work.

Thanks in advance, I would really love to know what's going wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you're overcomplicating this. If you need millisecond resolution, why not just use `setTimeout` to pause the audio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timeupdate` event fires only 3-4 times a second or so, nowhere near millisecond accuracy. Then again it's better than `setTimeout`/`setInterval` which fires only once per second if the tab is not active in google chrome (a common use case for audio file listening).

If however in your app you can ensure that the tab is active while listening, then `setTimeout` or `setInterval` is better as it can fire as often as 100 times per second.

Comment: Thanks kindly for the info, I didn't know that timeupdate had such a slow resolution. Do you know if the value is part of the spec somewhere? I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: @pat, http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html, `When the earliest possible position changes, then: if the current playback position is before the earliest possible position, the user agent must seek to the earliest possible position; otherwise, if the user agent has not fired a timeupdate event at the element in the past 15 to 250ms and is not still running event handlers for such an event, then the user agent must queue a task to fire a simple event named timeupdate at the element.`

Comment: The app I'm working on is an interactive transcript player, so I can be sure that the tab will be active. Now I guess I just need to figure out how to hook up a settimer inside my `HTMLAudioElement.prototype.playClip` function. I'll give it a shot, thanks again.